# Is it possible to edit and execute DB stored procedures?

Tags: postgresql

Emacs 27.1
PostgreSQL 9.6

In my java project I use plv8 scripts (stored procedures).
To edit and execute them I use external db client - DBeaver - https://dbeaver.io/

OK - it works just fine. But the question is:

Is it possible to edit and execute stored procedures directly from Emacs?